# How to capture output of subprocess OTHER than stdout/stderr?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program that I would like to launch via subprocess.  It can output to fd other than stdout and stderr.  Is there a way to capture data from an arbitrary fd?  I'd like to do something like the following, if my process is sending output to fd 9:

```
import subprocess, StringIO
redirector = StringIO.StringIO()
errno = subprocess.call(cmd, fd9=redirector)
#process the error code and data in redirector
```

I do **not** want to redirect the called process's output to fd 9 through stderr or stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the program opens file descriptor 9 (or whatever) after it starts running, then there is no way to do what you want.

If the program *does not* open file descriptor 9 itself, but gets it from the parent process, then you can do what you want with the `preexec_fn` argument to `subprocess.Popen`, but it is not as simple as setting something to a `StringIO` instance.  You have to create a pipe by hand, and you have to arrange to read from it in a timely fashion, or you *will* cause a deadlock.  Expect to write two or three hundred lines of code to get this 100% right.  I'm not going to put any sample code here because I don't want to make it look easier than it is.

In addition to [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), you will need [`os.pipe`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pipe), [`os.dup2`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.dup2), and [`os.read`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.read), and you will need to understand the underlying system primitives: 
 [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), [`dup2(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2), [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), and [`execve(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).

Now might be a good time to invest in a copy of [*Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment*](https://www.powells.com/biblio/62-9780321637734-1).

Comment: Ugh, thanks. The program does indeed open file descriptor 9 (or whatever) itself. Sounds like I need to look for another solution...

Comment: Can you control the name of the file that the program writes to, e.g. with command line options?  If so, the path of least resistance is probably to have it write to a file in a temporary directory ([`tempfile.mkdtemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp)), then read the contents of the file normally after the child process finishes.  You can use [`shutil.rmtree`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to clean up afterward.

Comment: Oops - I was in the middle of suggesting subprocess.Popen() with close_fds=false.  That obviously won't work if the parent doesn't have fd9 open, and reading/writing the same file isn't the same as streaming through a pipe.

Comment: @Zach. I can certainly send the output to a file. I asked this question because I assumed that I was missing something really cute in the subprocess module. Looks like not.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, you're not missing anything.  You can inherit any file descriptor you like from parent to child, but you can't steal a file out from under another process if it opens the file itself.